# Are samples correlated to the output resolution?

Tags: rendering

If I increase my resolution camera output have I to increase the render samples value too?
Are these two setting correlated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: No.

Light is sampled per pixel. So if you render with i.e. 200 Samples, Blender takes 200 Samples of each pixel. It doesn't matter if there are 5 oder 219928 pixels.